# RMI client is showing java.rmi.NotBoundException error

Tags: java, eclipse, rmi

please help with my code the rmi client is showing error but the server is running correctly.
I have run the server and it runs correctly but the client throws a `java.rmi.NotBoundException` which i don't understand which part of client code the error is

**this is the client code**

```
    package GUI;
    import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;



import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import rmiInterface.LoginInterface;

public class LaunchGUI {

    private JFrame frame;
    private LoginInterface myService;

    LoginGUI login;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    LaunchGUI window = new LaunchGUI(); // 3
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */

    String mySessionCookie = "not set";

    public LaunchGUI() {
        initialize(); // 2

    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        try {
            myService = (LoginInterface) Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost/Service");// 1
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("A problem occured: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Sign In");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // login = new LoginGUI();

                String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the password.");
                try {
                    String result = myService.login(str);
                    if (result.equals("wrong")) {
                        System.out.println("Wonrg Password. Try again!");
                    } else {
                        mySessionCookie = result;
                        System.out.println("Your login was successful.");
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("A problem occured: " + ex.toString());
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(24, 144, 97, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Sign Out");
        btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                try {
                    String result = myService.logout(mySessionCookie);
                    System.out.println("Logout: " + result);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("A problem occured: " + ex.toString());
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        btnNewButton_1.setBounds(297, 144, 97, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1);

        JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("View Score");
        btnNewButton_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String result;
                try {
                    result = myService.sayHello();
                    System.out.println("Result: " + result);
                } catch (RemoteException ex) {
                    System.out.println("A problem occured: " + ex.toString());
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        btnNewButton_2.setBounds(157, 199, 97, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_2);

        JButton btnNewButton_3 = new JButton("Start Game");
        btnNewButton_3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    String result = myService.getSecretMessage(mySessionCookie);
                    System.out.println("Result: " + result);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("A problem occured: " + ex.toString());
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        btnNewButton_3.setBounds(157, 144, 97, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_3);
    }
}
```

**This is the rmiInterface**

```
    package rmiInterface;

import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface LoginInterface extends Remote {

    public String sayHello() throws RemoteException;

    public String login(String password) throws RemoteException;

    public String getSecretMessage(String cookie) throws RemoteException;

    public String logout(String cookie) throws RemoteException;

}
```

**This is the server code**

```
    package Server;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Attempting to start the Login Server...");
        try {
            Service myHello = new Service();
            Registry reg = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1076);
            reg.rebind("Service", myHello);

            System.out.println("Service started. Welcome to the RMI Login Service!");

        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occured: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the service code**

```
package Server;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

import rmiInterface.LoginInterface;

public class Service extends UnicastRemoteObject implements LoginInterface {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String sessionCookie = "abc" + Math.random();

    public Service() throws RemoteException{
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /*
     * @Override public String sayHello() throws RemoteException {
     * 
     * return "Hello! Have a good day!"; }
     */

    @Override
    public String getSecretMessage(String cookie) throws RemoteException {
        if (cookie.equals(sessionCookie)) {
            return "This is a secret message: Alice is in a relationship with Bob. It is complicated.";
        } else {
            return "You must login to read this message";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String login(String password) throws RemoteException {
        /*
         * Note and Warning! This setup demonstrates the interaction between cookies and
         * login. Actually security is not in the scope of this demo. Usually you
         * wouldn't hardcode a password in production code but the password were to be
         * checked up against an (encrypted) database.
         */
        if (password != null && password.equals("hello")) {
            sessionCookie = "xyz" + Math.random();
            // timeout(5000)//my code so heck recording for answer :)
            return sessionCookie;
        } else {
            return "wrong";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String sayHello() throws RemoteException {

        return "Hello! Have a good day!";
    }

    public String logout(String cookie) throws RemoteException {
        sessionCookie = "abc" + Math.random();
        return "logout successful";
    }

    /*
     * @Override public String logout(String cookie) throws RemoteException {
     * sessionCookie = "abc" + Math.random(); return "logout successful"; }
     */

}
```

This client side is showing java.rmi.NotBoundException error please help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing different types of connection. To connect to RMI services you should pair this server code:

```
Registry reg = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
reg.rebind("Service", myHello);
```

with client code:

```
Registry reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(port);
Blah stub = (Blah) reg.lookup("Service");
```

Alternatively if you have started `rmiregistry` by:

```
set CLASSPATH=/path/to/your-client.jar
rmiregistry <port>
```

Then this server code:

```
Naming.rebind("rmi://"+hostname+":"+port+"/"+name, stub);
```

is matched by client code:

```
Blah stub = (Blah) Naming.lookup("rmi://"+hostname+":"+port+"/"+name);
```